# Visual Studio 2022: how to go to a variable/field/property's type definition in one step?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I seem to recall an option in pre-2022 versions of Visual Studio that allowed you to right-click on a variable, field, or property and select "Go to Type Definition".  This appears to be missing in VS 2022.

So, if I have a variable of type `Customer` called `myCust` and I want to see it's type definition, it is a two-step process:

1. Right-click the variable `myCust` and select Go to Definition, which takes me to there the variable is declared  (i.e., a line of code like `Customer myCust;`)
2. *Then* I need to right click on the type name `Customer` and again select Go to Definition....which finally takes me to where I wanted to go in the first place (that is, the definition of the class `Customer`)

Is there now no way to navigate directly with a single click from a variable instance to the the definition of that variable's type?

Comment: I have that option in VS 2022; also click and hit F12 does that

Answer (score 0):

Holding down Control when left-clicking will go to the definition of the type - that is working for me in VS 2022.
It appears that F12 is also a hotkey that can do this after you have clicked the type, but I prefer the Control + Click.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. You can get back Go to Type Definition with the following steps.

Tools > Customize > Commands > Context Menu > Editor Context Menus | Code Window > Add Command > Edit > Go to Type Definition

At this time, you can click the right button again to see Go to Type Definition. Of course, you can also define Go to Type Definition in the same way

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, I was able to add "Go To Type Definition" to the context menu using the method you described......but it is grayed out and thus doesn't actually let me navigate to the type definition of a highlighted variable.

Comment: @CadeBryant Hello, I tried the above operations in different versions of VS2022 recently updated, and this happened. This function should have been cut off in a certain update. I've submitted a fix suggestion to the official, and you can also submit a fix suggestion through this website<https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).>. More people's suggestions are always more likely to be heard. You can temporarily use Go to Definition or Peek Definition. Although it will be a little troublesome, at least it can solve the urgent need.